# Displaying images separately with ACF and Flexslider

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, flexslider

I have three separate fields in acf one for each image named slide_one, slide_two and slide_three. Now when I try to get the images to display using the code below nothing is being output. I am doing it this why and not using a loop like you usually as I'm wanting to have a separate text overlay for each image that I will have sliding in separately. This is the first step and it won't work. What an I doing wrong?

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">

    <?php 

    $image_one = get_field('slide_one');

    if( !empty($image_one ): ?>
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_one['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_one['alt']; ?>" />
      </li>  
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 

    $image_two = get_field('slide_two');

    if( !empty($image_two ): ?>
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_two['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_two['alt']; ?>" />
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php 

    $image_three = get_field('slide_three');

    if( !empty($image_three ): ?>
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_three['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_three['alt']; ?>" />
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code, though personally I'd use a repeater. What if you var_dump?

Comment: @powerbuoy Ok I'll look into using a repeater. Whats var_dump? how would I use it in this case

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: @powerbuoy I tried that and got nothing. I then tried just printing some text using echo and that didn't work. It's as if php is not working for me

Comment: try seeing what types of data you have, and if your fields are getting fetched : <?php echo '<pre>' . var_export(get_fields(), true) . '</pre>'; ?> - This way you can see all of your fields and the data they carry